# Powershell import csv to SQL queries, export multiple csvs

Tags: sql, powershell, variables, export

I'm struggling to get my head around this one, I've only just begun looking at scripting in SQL, and my powershell is very limited. The requirments are basically this:

Utilisng Powershell, import a csv file which contains one column that needs to feed into multiple SQL queries via a loop, exporting a seperate csv file for each different query.

example import of csv:
Project (heading)
1000
1001
1002

Powershell:

```
$importProjectsCSV = e:\Projects.csv
$server = servername
$database = database

import-csv $importProjectsCSV | ForEach-Object {
$query = "
Select ProjectLeader, ProjectTitle
FROM dbo.PROJECTS
Where Project = $_.Project;

Select ProjectClient, Name
FROM dbo.CLIENTS
Where Project = $_.Project;

$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.Connection = $connection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()


$dataset.Table[0] | Export-csv "E:\" + $_.ProjectName + ".csv"
$dataset.Table[1] | Export-csv "E:\" + $_.ProjectName + ".csv"
```

---

The problem is that the variable isn't coming into the SQL query. 
Is there a better way to handle this type of example?

Appreciate any pointers

Paul.

Comment: Shouldnt %Project be $_.Project ? $ is the variable sign in powershell, % would be the wildcard in SQL however I dont think it applies to a = statement, only to a like. I could be wrong though. Also you have a foreach loop and you're setting everytime the value to your query. only the last record in your csv would be searched. Can you add the other code as well? as to how you're making the dataset.  I'll make you a proper answer then :)

Comment: Ofcourse unless execute the sql query in the foreach loop, which would generate more load for the SQL Server + It would take longer for your script to execute. I would suggest retrieving records and then looping through those records to collect the records you want

Comment: Thanks Kage. I have added the rest of the code. And you were right, I had retyped my variable wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

I must admit i havent been able to test it, and personally i usually use c# to query sql servers. So i might have gone a bit wrong somewhere.

```
$importProjectsCSV = e:\Projects.csv
$server = servername
$database = database

$Projects =  Import-Csv -Path $importProjectsCSV | % {$_.Project}
$DS_Projects = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$DS_Clients = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$query_pro = "Select ProjectLeader, ProjectTitle, Project FROM dbo.PROJECTS";
$query_Clients = "Select ProjectClient, Name, Project FROM dbo.CLIENTS";

$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand();
$command.CommandText = $query_pro;
$sqlAdap = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($command)
$sqlAdap.Fill($DS_Projects)
$command2 = $connection.CreateCommand();
$command2.CommandText = $query_Clients;
$sqlAdap2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($command2)
$sqlAdap2.Fill($DS_Clients)
$connection.Close();

foreach($project in $Projects)
{
    $DS_Projects.Tables[0].Select("Project=$project") | Export-Csv "E:\$project.csv"
    $DS_Clients.Tables[0].Select("Project=$project") | Export-Csv "E:\$project.csv"
}
```

Comment: Looking close, as I can see the data is being pulled in. But when I go to use the select and export function ($DS_Projects.Tables[0].Select("Project=$project") | Export-Csv "E:\$project.csv") the file name it creates is "@{Project=1000} etc? It should just be "1000", "1001" etc. Can't see anything obvious looking at the import-csv coammand help. But if I manually specify the project then it works great!?

Comment: Ah think I got it finally. $Projects = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Projects.csv' | % {$_.Project}.

Comment: Ah yes that, sorry missed it. you could also put at the export part `$Project.Project`  but both are just as correct

Answer (score 0):

If I get every right you could do this with something like this:

```
$Projects = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Projects.csv'

ForEach ($Project in $Projects.Projects) {
    $Query= @" 
Select ProjectLeader, ProjectTitle
FROM dbo.PROJECTS
Where Project = '%{0}';
"@ -f $Project
    # just dummy action
    $results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "foo" -Database "bar" -Query $Query
    # In Case results is a dataset do something like
    $results | Export-Csv -Path ("E:\{0}.csv" -f $Project ) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I get an error on the export line , "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null." But if I do a write-host command of the csv I get the project numbers? Also How would this handle multiple Select queries that each need to be saved as seperate csv files? Thanks!